# Javascript delete a function

Tags: javascript

How can I delete a function

i.e

```
test=true;
delete test;
=> true

function test() {..}

delete test()
=> false
```

Delete usually works for variables but it doesn't work for functions.

Comment: Duplicate post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598058/how-do-undefined-or-remove-a-javascript-function

Comment: I checked that out before posting, its not the same. Im also not using jquery & i want to `delete` it not just declare it to null

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: If you set it to null it's as good as deleted since the function itself will no longer exist in memory (assuming you have no other references to it, and noting that actual garbage collection may not be instant).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What's the actual goal?  I suspect that deleting the function is not necessary to reach it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### No, you can not `delete` the result of a [function declaration](http://es5.github.io/#x13).

This is a part of the [language specification](http://es5.github.io/).

If you check out the description of the [delete operator](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.7) in JavaScript:

> If desc.[[Configurable]] is true, then
>
> - Remove the own property with name P from O.
> - Return true.

If you go to the browser and run the following in the console:

```
>function f(){}
>Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,"f")
```

You would get:

`Object {value: function, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false}`

#### What can be done:

You can however, assign the result to another value that is not a function, assuming that is your last reference to that function, garbage collection will occur and it will get de-allocated.

For all purposes other than `getOwnPropertyNames` `hasOwnProperty` and such, something like `f = undefined` should work. For those cases, you can use a functionExpression instead and assign that to a variable instead. However, for those purposes like `hasOwnProperty` it will fail, try it in the console!

```
function f(){}
f = undefined;
window.hasOwnProperty("f");//true
```

#### Some more notes on delete

- When your modern browser sees a `delete` statement, [that forces it to fall to hash map mode on objects](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/), so `delete` can be [very slow (perf)](http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-setting-to-undefined).
- In a managed language with a garbage collector, using `delete` might prove problematic. You don't have to handle your memory, the language does that for you.
- In the case you do want to use objects like a map, that's a valid use case and [it's on the way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) :)

Comment: @alex23 Note that I never claim that a function can't be deleted but that a function declaration can't be deleted. Function declarations (I linked to the spec) are when you do something like `function myFunction(){` and not when you do `var a = function(){` or `obj.property = function(){` (Those are variable declarations and object property declarations, followed by assignment to a _function expression_ ). It's a good point though, the fact my answer wasn't clear to you means it probably won't be clear to other people too, which makes this (and your) comments useful :)

Comment: I obviously meant "function declared with a function declaration", a function declaration is a part of code :)

Answer (score 13):

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) only works for properties of objects. If `test()` was inside an object, you could delete it, but if it's a stand alone function, you're stuck with it, unless you nullify it or define it as something else.

#### Object Delete

```
var obj = {
    test: function() {
        console.log("I'm a test");
    }
}

obj.test(); //I'm a test
delete obj.test;
obj.test(); //Nothin'
```

#### Function Reassign

```
function test() {
    console.log("I'm a test");
}

test(); // I'm a test

delete test;

test = undefined;

test(); // TypeError
```

Comment: You are invoking the function inside the delete statement in your second example, I assume that's not intentional?

Comment: if you write testfunc=undefined the variable testfunc is still a variable with no content. Better: **testfunc=null**;

Answer (score 5):

You could always do:

```
var testFunc = func() 
{
    // stuff here
}

//...
testFunc();
//...

testFunc = undefined;
```

delete in JavaScript has no bearing on freeing memory, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: What about `testFunc = undefined;`, wouldn't that be more appropriate?

Comment: @jgillich neither produces the same result as `delete` but out of the two `undefined` is more appropriate

Comment: Dont work correct this method : function fn(){

 return 5
}var x = fn;
delete x; x=undefined
undefined
fn()
5