# Is deleting reference to function, deleting the instance of the function?

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var NewRoom = new Room(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID)
NewRoom.addPlayer(socket.id);
NewRoom.addSocket(socket);
Rooms.push(NewRoom);
```

This is how I create a new room, now when everyone leaves I want to delete this instace of room.

Is deleting the reference to the function of array Rooms enough? or must I delete this with a special command?

This is how I delete it now:

```
if(output[0].ListOfSockets.length == 0)
{
    var index = Rooms.indexOf(output[0]);
    if (index > -1) 
    {
        console.log('Deleted room when there is no one else more');
        Rooms.splice(index, 1);
    }  
}
```

Here I am deleting the reference to the instance of the function, not the function itself.

If I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498247/javascript-delete-a-function) right and understand it good, when I delete the reference to the function, garbage collection will delete the function?

Comment: *If I read this right and understand it good, when I delete the reference to the function, garbage collection will delete the function?* You're not actually deleting the reference, you're only removing the reference from the array. If you don't reference it anywhere else anymore, the memory will be freed up by garbage collection, yes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it @nils,

Comment: @nils So if I want to delete the reference do i need to use the following code:  Rooms[index] = null?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Removing it from the array via `.splice` should suffice in your case.

Comment: @nils, Thanks, I understand now what you mean with your explanation. Thank you very much Nils!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object cannot be deleted. We can only wait for it to be garbage collected, if no-one is holding on to a reference to it.

What we can delete is a property on an object, such as `foo.bar`. This has no effect whatsoever on whatever it is that `foo.bar` used to refer to. It just removes the `bar` property from `foo`. However, if `foo.bar` was the last thing referring to whatever it did, then that thing can now be GC'd.

> delete this instance of room

As mentioned above, you cannot delete an object, including an instance of `Room`. What you can do is remove it from lists you are keeping which refer to it, and/or remove it from objects whose properties may be referring to it. Again, if those are the only remaining references, then the room will be GC'd.

> Is deleting the reference to the function of array Rooms enough? or must I delete this with a special command?

Again, you can't "delete a reference"--you can only delete a property on an object, whether array or object. I'm also not sure what you mean by "the function of array Rooms". I guess what you mean is "deleting the reference to the element in the array Rooms which is an instance created by the function (constructor) `Room`." Yes, that's enough. There's no other special way to "delete" it even if you wanted to.

Of course, a reference to an object can also be held in a variable. You cannot delete a variable, of course. What you can do is to set the variable to something else (often `null`), and if that variable was the last thing referring to the object previously held, then it can now be GC'd. However, it would be incorrect to say you are "deleting" the variable or the reference to the object that was being held in the variable. You are simply abandoning or orphaning the object, which makes it eligible for GC. If you really want to use the term "delete", you could say that it is the garbage collector that is deleting it, although it would be normal to use the word "freeing it".